# How do I plus plus a number to an item from an object in a array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I plus plus a number to an item from an object in a array?

I want to add a number plus one that is in an object that is also in an array

my db

```
"purchase" : [  
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f13f447b03b5f42e2b3b161"),
        "delete" : false,
        "qty" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f15381a63a90e3b4dd61f06"),
        "delete" : false,
        "qty" : 1
    }],
```

and plus plus qty item

and my code for this work

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    { $inc: { "purchase.qty": 1 } },
    { new: true }
).then((data) => {
    res.send(data);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(">> err: ", err);
});
```

Comment: Do you need to update all `qty`, or just those associated with a specific id? Also the limited code I see is suggesting me you always set the qty to 1 ```{ $inc: { "purchase.qty": 1 } },``` so not sure if that is correct or only the code to create a new row in the "db".

Comment: no .. No, just update the ID's qty he found

Comment: I think you are looking for the [positional update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)